# Where ругается - Unknown column 'группа=5220' in 'where clause'/

Tags: запрос, php, sql

```
$vstud=("SELECT * FROM `ведомость` where `группа=$g1` and `дисциплина=$g2`");
```

что не так с этим запросом where??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Кавычки неверно расставили.

```
$vstud=("SELECT * FROM `ведомость` where `группа`=$g1 and `дисциплина`=$g2");
```

Мало того. Если группа и дисциплина строковые, а не числовые, то

```
$vstud=("SELECT * FROM `ведомость` where `группа`='$g1' and `дисциплина`='$g2'");
```